# Is it possible to create a list and pull in all AD users and few details into it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

We are using SP2013. We need to create a list (custom/contact list) and need to pull the AD user and few details into it. It needs to be synchronized. Changes in AD must reflect into the list.

- Is user profile synchronization service something I must look at?
- Or custom C# coding to do this?

Please provide any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can read the users from active directory and add their details in a list. Following code reads the users from AD:

```
public List<Users> GetADUsers()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> lstADUsers = new List<Users>();
        string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=xxxx,DC=com"
        DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath); 
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
        SearchResult result;
        SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
        if (resultCol != null)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
            {
                string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
                result = resultCol[counter];
                if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") && 
                         result.Properties.Contains("mail") && 
                    result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
                {
                    Users objSurveyUsers = new Users();
                    objSurveyUsers.Email = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0] + 
                      "^" + (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.UserName = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.DisplayName = (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    lstADUsers.Add(objSurveyUsers);
                }
            }
        }
        return lstADUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

}
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp

You can then iterate through the users list and create items in the list based on user properties.

Comment: Do changes in AD reflect into the list? Do you mean I have to run this every day? Tiemr job?

Comment: What about this article? http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/How-to-build-sharepoint-phonebook-10-minutes.aspx

Comment: The changes in AD won't reflect in the list. You will need to code it using may be timer job. The link you provided is a third party product. I haven't used it.

Comment: Is user profile synchronization service something I must look at?

Comment: Even then you will have to write code to map users from User Profile service to the list and update it regularly.

Comment: OK which one would be good the UP service or the custom C# code..?

Comment: Since all you need is to create a contacts list I think it will be better not to go with User profile service. In any case you will need to write custom code to read users and update list regularly.

Comment: OK, I am going to use this code in timer job to be run everyy day.. Is that OK.. Also I want to know what I have to use for: string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=xxxx,DC=com"

Comment: The schedule of timer job will depend on the frequency of new and updated users. You need to provide domain information in the above code. See this for more info: http://www.youcanlearnseries.com/Programming%20Tips/CSharp/LDAPReader.aspx

Comment: What about http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2009/06/17/user-profiles-and-the-user-information-list-or-userinfo-table.aspx ? Looks like it is an OOTB feature

Comment: User Information List is the out of the box SP List and User profile service updates this list. However, as you mentioned in the question you wanted to update a custom list which user profile service cannot update.

Comment: OK, we are planning to use this list and add user properties to this.